# How I can sort these data with Missing data in R

Tags: r

Here is a sample of my data :

```html
df<-read.table (text="ID    Name    Surname Colour  A1  A2  A3  Flow1   Day1    M1  M2  M3  Flow2   Day2    P1  P2  P3  Flow3   Day3
12  John    Smith   A   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  N
12  John    Smith   B   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  N
12  John    Smith   M   4   4   4   A   N   4   3   3   B   Y   2   3   2   Q   N
12  John    Smith   N   2   3   3   D   N   3   1   2   G   Y   3   3   2   R   N
22  Rose    Billy   OM  3   3   3   C   N   3   3   3   O   Y   3   4   4   G   N
22  Rose    Billy   OZ  4   4   4   F   N   4   4   4   P   N   5   5   5   G   N
22  Rose    Billy   QR  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
22  Rose    Billy   QP  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get this outcome:

```html
 

   out<-read.table (text="ID    Name    Surname Colour  A1  A2  A3  Flow1   Day1    M1  M2  M3  Flow2   Day2    P1  P2  P3  Flow3   Day3
    12  John    Smith   M   4   4   4   A   N   4   3   3   B   Y   2   3   2   Q   N
    12  John    Smith   N   2   3   3   D   N   3   1   2   G   Y   3   3   2   R   N
    22  Rose    Billy   OM  3   3   3   C   N   3   3   3   O   Y   3   4   4   G   N
    22  Rose    Billy   OZ  4   4   4   F   N   4   4   4   P   N   5   5   5   G   N

    ", header=TRUE)
```

As you can see, I want to get the data for each colour and reduce my data set.

Comment: I think it is not a deuplicate query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `across` to `filter` - Based on the input data/expected output, it seems to remove rows where the columns ('A1' to 'Day3') are all `NA`s

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%    
   filter(across(A1:Day3,  complete.cases))
```

-output

```
ID Name Surname Colour A1 A2 A3 Flow1 Day1 M1 M2 M3 Flow2 Day2 P1 P2 P3 Flow3 Day3
1 12 John   Smith      M  4  4  4     A    N  4  3  3     B    Y  2  3  2     Q    N
2 12 John   Smith      N  2  3  3     D    N  3  1  2     G    Y  3  3  2     R    N
3 22 Rose   Billy     OM  3  3  3     C    N  3  3  3     O    Y  3  4  4     G    N
4 22 Rose   Billy     OZ  4  4  4     F    N  4  4  4     P    N  5  5  5     G    N
```

Comment: Thank you,  but when I continue data for other colours, I do not get the data, Can we do it?

Comment: Can we do it for columns? For example, if I have  data until Day6

Comment: Sorry, If you look at colour ,, you will see the other colours QR and Qand QP. So I want to get these data in outcome for these coloures that are availavle in other columns.  Your help appriciated

Comment: @user330 isn't this output same as your expected 'out`

Comment: Thanks, it does work for these data, thank you- But when I have more similar data, say until day 6 as last coloumn, the code dioes not work

Comment: @user330 I didn't understand the logic based on colors QR, Q, QP which you didn't explain in your post.

Comment: i.e. where is the QR matching in other columns?  I see only a single letter in Flow columns

Comment: In the colour coloumn, you see 8 colours, in your codes, only codes M, N, OM and OZ are appeared , which is good. I want to see other colurs for A, B, QR and QP when I have other similar colunmns.

Comment: @user330 can you update your post with an example that doesn't work with the code along with expected output so that it becomes more clear

Comment: @user330 sure, will check that. thanks

Comment: @user330 If i understand the pattern, you have some columns have only NA should be grouped together where as no NA in a different way

Answer (score 2):

We could use `na.omit()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  na.omit()
```

```
ID Name Surname Colour A1 A2 A3 Flow1 Day1 M1 M2 M3 Flow2 Day2 P1 P2 P3 Flow3 Day3
3 12 John   Smith      M  4  4  4     A    N  4  3  3     B    Y  2  3  2     Q    N
4 12 John   Smith      N  2  3  3     D    N  3  1  2     G    Y  3  3  2     R    N
5 22 Rose   Billy     OM  3  3  3     C    N  3  3  3     O    Y  3  4  4     G    N
6 22 Rose   Billy     OZ  4  4  4     F    N  4  4  4     P    N  5  5  5     G    N
```

Comment: Why this does not work when I continue it until Day 6. any help?

Comment: If your data is in the same structure it should work also with any additional Day. So maybe you could `dput` the new data (until day 6).